# Layer.call is not executed eagerly

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I wrote a layer, which does nothing

```py
class Fractal2D(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, kernel_size_range):
        super(Fractal2D, self).__init__()
        self.kernel_size_range = kernel_size_range
    
    def build(self, inputs):
        print(f'build executes eagerly: {tf.executing_eagerly()}')
        return inputs
    
    def call(self, inputs):
        print(f'call executes eagerly: {tf.executing_eagerly()}')
        return inputs
```

and made a model

```py
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape=(224, 224, 3), batch_size=32),
    Fractal2D(kernel_size_range=(3, 41)),
    hub.KerasLayer("https://tfhub.dev/google/tf2-preview/mobilenet_v2/feature_vector/4", output_shape=[1280],
                   trainable=False),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(DIAGNOSIS_NUMBER, activation='softmax')
])
```

the output from the cell is

```
build executes eagerly: True 
call executes eagerly: False
```

When I train the model

```py
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(training_set, validation_data=validation_set, epochs=20)
```

I get

```
 Epoch 1/20
 call executes eagerly: False
 call executes eagerly: False
```

Questions:

1. Why build and call method are executed, when the model is instantiated?
2. Why call method is NOT executed eagerly, if the eager execution is the default method of execution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `call` method of the custom layer is automatically decorated with `@tf.function`, which essentially creates a dataflow graph on the first call and then executes this graph on all subsequent calls. Why is this relevant to your question? Because according to the [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/executing_eagerly) on `tf.executing_eagerly()`:

> Eager execution is enabled by default and this API returns True in most of cases. However, this API might return False in the following use cases.
>
> - Executing inside tf.function, unless under tf.init_scope or tf.config.run_functions_eagerly(True) is previously called.
> - Executing inside a transformation function for tf.dataset.
> - tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution() is called.

So let's try see what happens when using `tf.init_scope`:

```py
import tensorflow_hub as hub
import tensorflow as tf

class Fractal2D(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, kernel_size_range):
        super(Fractal2D, self).__init__()
        self.kernel_size_range = kernel_size_range
    
    def build(self, inputs):
        print(f'build executes eagerly: {tf.executing_eagerly()}')
        return inputs
    
    def call(self, inputs):
        with tf.init_scope():
          print(f'call executes eagerly: {tf.executing_eagerly()}')
        return inputs

model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape=(224, 224, 3), batch_size=1),
    Fractal2D(kernel_size_range=(3, 41)),
    hub.KerasLayer("https://tfhub.dev/google/tf2-preview/mobilenet_v2/feature_vector/4", output_shape=[1280],
                   trainable=False),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
])
training_set = tf.random.normal((1, 224, 224, 3))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(training_set, tf.random.normal((1, 1)), epochs=2)
```

```
build executes eagerly: True
call executes eagerly: True
Epoch 1/2
call executes eagerly: True
call executes eagerly: True
1/1 [==============================] - 4s 4s/step - loss: 0.2856 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 2/2
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 36ms/step - loss: 0.1641 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
<keras.callbacks.History at 0x7f8836515710>
```

Seems to be consistent with the docs.

Comment: do you know, why build and call are called after model description. Not only after fit method?

Comment: Check out the docs https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model?version=nightly#compile and source code. During `model.compile`, the model will be wrapped in a tf.function.

Comment: I have the build/call output after Sequential before compile. I used Jupyter Notebook.

Comment: Yes, this behavior is also documented here: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Layer?version=nightly. The optional `build()` method is invoked by the first __call__() to the layer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can run eager mode even if you use a custom layer. Your model runs in graph mode because of the 'model.fit()' method, to run under eager mode you have to write your own training loop from scratch, you can use the GradientTape.
[[1]: https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/customizing_what_happens_in_fit](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/customizing_what_happens_in_fit)